# jQuery flot doesn't draw pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flot

I am working with jQuery flot, right now I can make a chart with lines and points but my client need to have a pie chart for diagnostics, so I am trying to make it but with no success...
I don't know why my flot pie chart don't show the chart...maybe you can help me with my issue.

here is the script of my flot inside of the page:

```
<script src="js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the db call in graficas6.php:

```
<?php
include 'includes/confs.php';
    $return_arr = array();
$sql = $conn->prepare("select diagnostico, 
count(diagnostico) from 
( select diagnostico as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico1 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico2 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico3 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO) 
t group by t.diagnostico");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    $return_arr[] = $row;   
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Here is the script to make the chart in jschartrep.php:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
$.ajax({ 
    url: "graficas6.php", 
    method: "GET", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(series) {
        var data = [series];
        alert(data);
        $.plot($("#pie"), data, {
            pie: { 
                show: true,
                showLabel: true
            }, legend: { 
                show: true
            }
        });
     }
});  
</script>
```

And the div inside of my page:

```
<?php include 'graficas6.php'; ?>
<?php include 'jschartrep.php'; ?>
<div id="pie" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

Right now only show the data like this:

```
[
    {
        "diagnostico": "acne",
        "count(diagnostico)": "1"
    },
    {
        "diagnostico": "herpes",
        "count(diagnostico)": "1"
    },
    {
        "diagnostico": "melanoma",
        "count(diagnostico)": "2"
    }
]
```

Can you give me a clue?

---

EDIT WITH NEW CODE:

In graficas6.php:

```
<?php
include 'include/configs.php';
$sql = $conn->prepare("select diagnostico, 
count(diagnostico) from 
( select diagnostico as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico1 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico2 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico3 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO) 
t group by t.diagnostico");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {

  $data[] = array("label" => $row["diagnostico"], "data" => $row["count(diagnostico)"]); 
}
?>
```

In jschartrep.php

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
var data = [
{
"label": dataset1,
pie: {
show: true,
radius: 3/4,
label: {
show: true,
radius: 3/4,
formatter: function(label, series)
{
return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
},
background: 
{
opacity: 0.5,
color: '#000'
}}}}
];
var plot = $("#pie");
$.plot( plot , data );
}); 
</script>
```

here the Prt Scr:
[image]

Now is showing a empty line chart ...I need a pie chart...where is the error in the code??

And this is the db data:

```
[{"label":"acne","data":"1"},{"label":"herpes","data":"1"},{"label":"melanoma","data":"2"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is in an incorrect format.  According to the documentation, it should look like:

```
    var data = [
        { label: "Series1",  data: 10},
        { label: "Series2",  data: 30}
    ];
```

So modify your PHP to:

```
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
  $return_arr[] = array("label" => $row["diagnostico"], "data" => $row["count(diagnostico)"]);  
}
```

This should produce an array as:

```
    var data = [
        { label: "acne",  data: 1},
        { label: "herpes",  data: 1},
        { label: "melanoma",  data: 2} 
    ];
```

Also note, your data must be numeric.  So, you might need to cast the `$row["count(diagnostico)"]` to an integer with `(int) $row["count(diagnostico)"]`.  Not sure why this would be necessary (since they should be ints coming out of the database) but in your sample data the counts are strings...

**My standard PHP disclaimer**:  I don't code in it, I don't know it, I don't like, so please excuse any typos in the above.

Comment: thank you for your support. I am working with the code and now the chart is showing but empty and in line or points format not in pie format that I need it. I change the code to another I found but I still have the issue

Comment: @asterix_jv, your `data` is still strings: `"data":"1"` (see the quotes around the 1).  It needs to be numeric.  In the loop try replacing `$row["count(diagnostico)"]` with `(int) $row["count(diagnostico)"]` as I stated in above.

Comment: @asterix_jv, also, why did you modify `jschartrep.php`?  How you had it originally was correct.

Comment: Hi @Mark, sorry my mistake..I put the first script in jschartrep.php but I change it a little bit because I have an error inside. Now show me the legend but not the pie chart just the empty line chart. Here the code in jschartrep.php: `<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'> 
$(function () { $.ajax({ url: "graficas6.php", 
method: "GET", dataType: "json", success: function(series) {
var data = <?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>;
$.plot($("#pie"), data, { pie: { show: true, showLabel: true },
legend: { show: true } }); } }); }); 
</script>` I don't know why pie chart don't show ...

Comment: @asterix_jv, did you fix the `data` as strings?

Comment: yes here is graficas6.php like you said me: `<?php
include 'include/configs.php';
$sql = $conn->prepare("select diagnostico, 
count(diagnostico) from 
( select diagnostico as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico1 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico2 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO union all select diagnostico3 as diagnostico from DIAGNOSTICO) 
t group by t.diagnostico");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {

  $return_arr[] = array("label" => $row["diagnostico"], "data" => (int) $row["count(diagnostico)"]); 
}
?>`

Comment: Hi @Mark, I can do it! now show me all...the error was inside of jschartrep.php the was miss a littler code inside of $plot.. thank you for your great support!

Comment: Here is the script: `<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'> 
$(function () {
 $.ajax({ 
     url: "graficas6.php", 
     method: "GET", 
     dataType: "json", 
     success: function(series) {
         var data = <?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>;
    $.plot($("#pie"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                innerRadius: 0.5,
                show: true
            }
        },
         legend: {
            show: true
        },
        grid: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', borderColor: 'transparent' }
    });
      }
 });  
}); 
</script>`

Comment: Tldr: data's value should not be enclosed in quotes